# Reduce function creating an array with half the data

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, reduce

I am trying to sort data into separate arrays based on the value of a property inside each object. I am using a reduce function which is new to me and still quite confusing.

My data looks like this:

```
const data = [{
            score: 2,
            category: "date of admission"
            subcategory: 2-days
         }, { score: 12,
            category: "Vitals",
            subcategory: "bloodPressure",
           },{
            score: 4,
            category: "date of admission"
            subcategory: 3-days
         }...]
```

My reduce function looks like this:

```
const grouped = data.reduce((cat, item, index, data) => {
      for (index = 0; data.length; index++) {
        cat[item.category] = [];
        cat[item.category].push(item);
        return cat;
      }
    }, {});
```

The problem Im having is the output when I `console.log(grouped)` each array will have the correct category label but inside the array there is only ever 1 object. Even tho the data may have more than one item with the same category. Im not sure what Im doing wrong here. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What happens if you put the return statement outside of the for loop?

Comment: I get the same result :/

Comment: Why do you want to use `reduce`? If you want to optimize for readability, which is a good thing, you should not use `reduce`. Use a simple for-loop, or `filter` is my suggestion.

Comment: Can you post the result that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
const grouped = data.reduce((catetories, item) => {
    const category = catetories[item.category] || [];
    return {
        ...catetories,
        [item.category]: [
            ...category,
            item,
        ]
    }
}, {});

const groupedArr = Object.keys(grouped).map((key) => grouped[key]);
```

Comment: Forgot you needed an array of arrays, so I added a `groupedArr` with that exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
            score: 2,
            category: "date of admission",
            subcategory: "2-days"
         }, { score: 12,
            category: "Vitals",
            subcategory: "bloodPressure",
           },{
            score: 4,
            category: "date of admission",
            subcategory: "3-days"
         }];

const cat = {};
for (let c of data) {
   if (cat[c.category]) {
      cat[c.category].push(c);
   } else {
      cat[c.category] = [c];
   }
}
console.log(cat)
```